# Hydra returning random and wrong password

Tags: hydra, dvwa

I tried everything, I followed a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGeSQ7STHaE&ab_channel=CartesianCaramel I did the exact same thing.

Why does hydra return wrong and random passwords for this command?

```
sudo hydra 172.17.0.2 http-form-post "/login.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:H=Cookie\: PHPSESSID=bc4tdskieapdpbdgarpgg0e975; security=low:F=Login failed" -l admin -P password.txt -f
```

I have a password.txt file with random passwords. I tried the two with the good one and the wrong passwords only. In any case, hydra is returning me a random password with the same command.

- it is the right ip address
- it is a form post
- the login.php page doesn't return a location
- I tried `-p pass` with a wrong password, and it says it works!
- I used curl and Burp Suite to see the returning string when the wrong password is entered is `Login failed`.
- I tried without the Cookies
- I tried without -f or -V or both, I waited, I changed of ip address,

I don't know what to do. I can't find posts about random passwords being returned or this kind of problem.

I used it with docker. The image is https://hub.docker.com/r/vulnerables/web-dvwa/

Comment: The obvious reason is that it stops returning "Login failed" during a brute force